# MySQL Query needed to update existing date by 8

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database and there are only 4 records (out 10 of 10,000's) that need to have their date field routinely updated by 8 days. The other records need to be left alone. This has to be able to be run week after week after week...

Data looks like this (lot more data available). The primary ID will be constant and is not displayed below.

Starting Data looks like:

```
'title 1','2016-09-03 00:00:00'
'title 1','2016-09-04 00:00:00'    
'title 2','2016-09-05 00:00:00'
'title 2','2016-09-06 00:00:00'
....
'title 10','2016-09-10 00:00:00'
'title 10','2016-09-11 00:00:00'    
'title 11','2016-09-12 00:00:00'
'title 11','2016-09-13 00:00:00'
```

Ending Data looks like:

```
'title 1','2016-09-07 00:00:00'
'title 1','2016-09-08 00:00:00'    
'title 2','2016-09-09 00:00:00'
'title 2','2016-09-10 00:00:00'
....
'title 10','2016-09-14 00:00:00'
'title 10','2016-09-15 00:00:00'    
'title 11','2016-09-16 00:00:00'
'title 11','2016-09-17 00:00:00'
```

It doesn't matter what the existing date is, the query needs to simply add 4 days to it and update the row accordingly.

Can I do this in one statement or do I need to perform a query to select the data, then perform a second query to do the the update?

Comment: How do you decide which rows do and don't get updated?

Comment: The IDs are known ahead of time and do not change from week to week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this could work

```
UPDATE titles
SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 8 DAY)
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting clarification on the IDs before answering. Your solution worked perfectly. Marking this correct since you commented first even though your answer wasn't first.

Answer (score 1):

If you can `SELECT` the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Then you can `UPDATE` the same subset of rows:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET date = date + INTERVAL 4 DAY
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Yes, I can perform the select as you indicated. I tried something close to your solution but wasn't aware of the **interval** function. Great solution.